# How to remove white space from filename?

Tags: php

I want to rename a file while download it. Suppose my download link is "/img/o%20o%20o.png"

I want to make a system that rename this file when downlod it to  "o o o.png". 
How I can do it?

Comment: `urlencode()`/`urldecode()`

Comment: Has this something to do with PHP or are you just looking for a browser feature?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$encodedPath = "/img/o%20o%20o.png";
$stringArray = explode('/', $encodedPath);// split the encoded path by the delimiter '/'
$fileName = end($stringArray);// get the last element of the string array which is gonna be the filename
echo urldecode($fileName);// decode the filename
```

This would output:

`o o o.png`

Hope this helps.